# Slowdown at increased number of processes for HPC with fat-tree architecture

Tags: mpi, hpc

I've noticed something particularly odd about a simple program I've been running on a HPC with a fat tree architecture and I'm not exactly sure why I'm getting the results I'm getting.

The program I've created simply prints the runtime of a program on a varying number of processes (using MPI). I experimented by varying the number of processes by 2^n from 2 to 256, and while the execution time for each process tends to decrease as the number of processes increases from 2 to 8 processes, this time jumps dramatically at 64 processes.

Could this be because of the architecture, itself? I'd imagine that the execution time would decrease with respect to the number of processes, but this doesn't seem to be the case past a certain threshold of processes.

Comment: Could it be that you have 64 cores per node? Then going beyond 64 means you go from shared memory to networked distributed memory. Also: are you using weak scaling? Otherwise it may be because your problem is too small.

Comment: There are 48 cores per node (2 processors with 24 cores each). Would using "mpirun -np 64 program" run the program on 16 cores or processes?

Comment: Using `-np 64` just tell MPI to create 64 process and no more. It does not specify where the process are. Some can be located on the same machine while not others. MPI implementations *tends* to pack thread in a deterministic way that is often quite good for performance. You can manually specify this to your implementation. Moreover, there is a host file used to define where the process can be executed. Note that some implementation maps processes to hardware threads while other map each process on each core. Which implementation do you use? Is SMT enabled? Please add more information.

Comment: I'm not explicitly mapping processes to cores. I'm not familiar with which implementation I'm using, but I'd imagine it'd be the most vanilla version. If it helps, I use the intelmpi compiler, compile with mpiicc -0, and run with the above command. I'm not sure how to determine if SMT is enabled, but I'll look into that now.

Comment: For the implementation, I think `mpirun --version` should provide it. I think it should be Intel MPI. For the SMP you can get this information with hw-loc (typically with ls-topo). By default IMPI should bind processes and it can be tuned with [this](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mpi-developer-reference-linux/top/environment-variable-reference/process-pinning/environment-variables-for-process-pinning.html).

Comment: To show the process placement on nodes, the best is to print it manually using `hostname` as [described in the documentation](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mpi-developer-guide-linux/top/running-applications/controlling-process-placement.html). Check if multiple nodes are used. Note that `I_MPI_DEBUG` may help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue a while ago after reading the documentation (go figure) and wanted to post the solution here in case anyone had a similar issue. On the HPC I was using (AFRL's Mustang), I was executing my programs with mpirun on the login node. The documentation clearly states that jobs need to be submitted via a batch script per section 6 of the user guide:

https://www.afrl.hpc.mil/docs/mustangQuickStartGuide.html#jobSubmit